# At the beginning of a chapter or an article , is "we provide" or "we'll provide" better, or no difference?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, expressions

From this book "Deep Learning and Convolutional Neural Networks for Medical Image Computing"

> Abstract Computerized algorithms and solutions in processing and
>   diagnosis mammography X-ray, cardiovascular CT/MRI scans, and
>   microscopy image play an important role in disease detection and
>   computer-aided decision-making. Machine learning techniques have
>   powered many aspects in medical investigations and clini- cal
>   practice. Recently, deep learning is emerging a leading machine
>   learning tool in computer vision and begins attracting considerable
>   attentions in medical imaging. `In this chapter, we provide a snapshot`
>   of this fast growing field specifically for mammography,
>   cardiovascular, and microscopy image analysis.

this is beginning of the chapter 2 of that book, to give the outline of this chapter, which expression is better

expression_1:

> In this chapter, `we provide` a snapshot of this fast growing field
>   specifically for mammography

expression_2

> In this chapter, `we'll provide` a snapshot of this fast growing field
>   specifically for mammography

Comment: Better in what respect? Both are grammatical and idiomatic (to me at least, AmE) and semantically convey the same meaning

Comment: A book using "we'll provide" makes more likely as if I am sitting in a classroom than "we provide"

Comment: Opinion based, but "we provide" sounds better to me, as it has already been provided - just perhaps not read (by you) yet.