# How to express a scenario more likely than the other clearly and concisely?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, expressions

I just replied a comments in a [post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/218691/98358), then I realized that this expression may need some improvement.

> A book using "we'll provide" makes more likely as if I am sitting in a
>   classroom than "we provide"

By "sitting in a classroom", I mean something like person to person, face to face, lively.

what I want to suggest is the first scenario has higher probability to have me Imagine I am sitting in a classroom than the 2nd scenario(expression)

how to express the meaning above clearly and concisely?

Comment: *[If a textbook is written using informal contracted forms] **it feels more like** [I am sitting in a classroom].* Or ***...it gives me the feeling / sense / impression** [that]...*

Comment: Thanks for you comments. It seems that "it gives me the feeling" does not express the implication of "more".

Comment: Okay - *[blah blah] **I'm more likely to feel as if** [blah blah]* (or ***...more likely to feel like...*** - few native speakers would be bothered about the ***likely / like*** juxtaposition there). But in practice, even if you specifically and very deliberately *intended* to directly refer to the ***likelihood*** (saying that you're more ***likely*** to feel that way, rather than simply saying you ***do*** or ***will*** feel that way), most of your audience probably wouldn't notice any difference in the overall meaning, given the rest of the context.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Please mv your comments to answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I don't really like the question itself, in its current form (it feels like Off Topic "writing advice"). Note that (in principle, at least) there's a difference between being ***more likely to feel** [relaxed]* and being ***likely to feel more** [relaxed]*. Sticking more closely to your original text, perhaps *I'm more likely to feel as if I'm sitting in a classroom with a book that uses "we'll provide" rather than "we will provide".*

Comment: The example sentence doesn't seem grammatical to me. I also don't understand what it's trying to express, so I can't say how it should be rephrased. Perhaps I'm simply confused by the, to me, illogical statement that "we'll provide" seems more scholarly (?) than "we provide." If that's what you're trying to say . . .

Comment: @JasonBassford I've updated OP. "By "sitting in a classroom", I mean something like person to person, face to face, lively." Is this clear now?

Comment: Slightly, but not really. This would be much better: *A book with the text "we'll provide" is more likely to be found in a classroom than a book with the text "we provide."* That seems completely grammatical to me. I don't have a clue why that would be a conclusion anybody would reach, but the sentence, in terms of the words pieced together, has a natural construction.